# Google Reporting API: Customer Usage Report

Tags: google-apps-script, google-reporting-api

I am trying to generate a usage report from my domain on all my users. I would like to be able to use these parameters: num_1day_logins, num_7day_logins,num_30day_logins. So that I can show how adoption of Google Apps in our domain is increasing or decreasing. The code below is from Google. Which is close to what I would like to do, but not exactly. I think it's possible to customize this code to what I would like to do, but I don't know how.

Thanks.

```
function generateUserUsageReport() {
var today = new Date();
var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var timezone = Session.getTimeZone();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
var parameters = [
'accounts:last_login_time',
'gmail:num_emails_received',
'docs:num_docs'
];
var rows = [];
var pageToken, page;
do {
page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date, {
  parameters: parameters.join(','),
  maxResults: 500,
  pageToken: pageToken
});
var reports = page.usageReports;
if (reports) {
  for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
    var report = reports[i];
    var parameterValues = getParameterValues(report.parameters);
    var row = [
      report.date,
      report.entity.userEmail,
      parameterValues['accounts:last_login_time'],
      parameterValues['gmail:num_emails_received'],
      parameterValues['docs:num_docs']
    ];
    rows.push(row);
  }
}
pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);

if (rows.length > 0) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Google Apps User Usage Report');
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// Append the headers.
var headers = ['Date', 'User', 'Last Login', 'Num Emails Received',
    'Num Docs'];
sheet.appendRow(headers);

// Append the results.
sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(rows);

Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
 } else {
 Logger.log('No results returned.');
}
}

/**
* Gets a map of parameter names to values from an array of parameter    objects.
* @param {Array} parameters An array of parameter objects.
* @return {Object} A map from parameter names to their values.
*/
function getParameterValues(parameters) {
return parameters.reduce(function(result, parameter) {
var name = parameter.name;
var value;
if (parameter.intValue !== undefined) {
  value = parameter.intValue;
} else if (parameter.stringValue !== undefined) {
  value = parameter.stringValue;
} else if (parameter.datetimeValue !== undefined) {
  value = new Date(parameter.datetimeValue);
} else if (parameter.boolValue !== undefined) {
  value = parameter.boolValue;
}
result[name] = value;
return result;
}, {});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code with the parameters you were looking for.

```
function generateUserUsageReport() {
var today = new Date();
var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
var parameters = [
'accounts:num_1day_logins',
'accounts:num_7day_logins',
'accounts:num_30day_logins'
];
var rows = [];
var pageToken, page;
do {
page = AdminReports.CustomerUsageReports.get(date, {
  parameters: parameters.join(','),
  maxResults: 500,
  pageToken: pageToken
});
var reports = page.usageReports;
if (reports) {
  for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
    var report = reports[i];
    var parameterValues = getParameterValues(report.parameters);
    var row = [
      report.date,
      parameterValues['accounts:num_1day_logins'],
      parameterValues['accounts:num_7day_logins'],
      parameterValues['accounts:num_30day_logins']
    ];
    rows.push(row);
  }
}
pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);

if (rows.length > 0) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Google Apps User Usage Report');
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// Append the headers.
var headers = ['Date', '1day_logins', '7day_logins',
    '30day_logins'];
sheet.appendRow(headers);

// Append the results.
sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(rows);

Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s', spreadsheet.getUrl());
 } else {
 Logger.log('No results returned.');
}
}

/**
* Gets a map of parameter names to values from an array of parameter    objects.
* @param {Array} parameters An array of parameter objects.
* @return {Object} A map from parameter names to their values.
*/
function getParameterValues(parameters) {
return parameters.reduce(function(result, parameter) {
var name = parameter.name;
var value;
if (parameter.intValue !== undefined) {
  value = parameter.intValue;
} else if (parameter.stringValue !== undefined) {
  value = parameter.stringValue;
} else if (parameter.datetimeValue !== undefined) {
  value = new Date(parameter.datetimeValue);
} else if (parameter.boolValue !== undefined) {
  value = parameter.boolValue;
}
result[name] = value;
return result;
}, {});
}
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks. How would I go about changing the start date from oneWeekAgo to say 1 month ago or 3 months ago?

Comment: var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
The value '7' specifies how many days ago to look. Change 7 to 30 or 90 to go back further in time.

Comment: is it possible to modify this script so that I can run a report for a specific month? So for example: I want to see the 1,7,and 30 day logins for everyday in April, 2015.

Comment: Take a look at the Date.parse() method...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: How would I go about modifying the script so that every time it runs, the latest data is added to the row below instead of always creating a new spreadsheet?

Comment: Change var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Google Apps User Usage Report');  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(); to var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.SpreadsheetApp.openById('id-of-the-spreadsheet'); var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('MyLogSheet-or-whatever-you-call-it');

Comment: added the above code and it works as far as adding the data to the existing sheet. I want to run this script based on a time trigger everyday. The issue is that the previous days data is being replaced. I want the next days data to be added to the next row. I have tried adding sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, headers.length).setValues(rows).getLastRow()+1; this doesn't work.