# Data retrieved from REST API to Databrick data store

Tags: pyspark, databricks

A newbie spark question. I'm trying to read data from REST API which returns data by pagination. To retrieve data, I'll have call same API say 5 times. I would like to save that data in databrick table. The result of API is in json. Idea is to make a API call everyday and save data partitioned by date. All examples lead to single API call.

Any pointers? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing something similar with the Google Api. Most good Apis will handle paging by returning a pagination token - e.g. you ask for the first X records and it gives a token to show it has more records, so you keep looping until there are no more records.

On the Spark side of things, you could use Row to keep adding the return data to a List and then finally convert it to a Dataframe (after which you can do all the usual goodness in databricks:  (Python code using Google Api Python Sdk, abbreviated for size)
 but you shuold get the idea:)

```
from pyspark.sql import *

..
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, subject=IMPERSONATED_USER)
service = build('admin', 'reports_v1', credentials=credentials)   #https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#build-the-service-object

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903125/google-reporting-api-customer-usage-report 
# https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/reports_v1/python/latest/admin_reports_v1.userUsageReport.html
# https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started#build-the-service-object
print('Hitting Google Admin Reports - User Usage Api')
request = service.userUsageReport().get(userKey=keyUserFilter, date=keyDateFilter, filters=fieldFilter, maxResults=pageSize, parameters=fieldSelect)

rows = []
# get all pages until there are none left
while request != None:
  response = request.execute()
  rows.append(Row(id=ur.get("id"), item=response.get("item")))  
  request = service.userUsageReport().get_next(request, response)

print("end of loop")
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rows)

display(df1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, I didn't check it earlier. The API I'm hitting has about 4400 pages. Instead of storing all of that data in memory while collecting all results, I decided to save results in smaller chuck one per each request and appending it to a DF eventually.

Comment: Yes, I do the same thing - I had to get 2000 pages of 1000 recors (2 million records). So each pageset is written to disk as Parquet or json. Then at the end I read them all with a standard read*. Works very well and very scalable

Comment: while request != None:
  apiCallCount = apiCallCount + 1
  response = request.execute()
  print("Loop {0} - etag {1}" .format(apiCallCount, response.get("etag")))
   
  fileName = "googleuserusage-{0}-{1}.json" .format(apiCallCount, dateToProcess)
  tempDBFSLocalPathwithFileName = "{0}{1}{2}/{3}" .format(localFileApiMountPath, datalakePath, formatDateIntoPartitionString(dateToProcess), fileName)
  
  writeJsonToDataLake(tempDBFSLocalPathwithFileName, response)

  request = service.userUsageReport().get_next(request, response)

Comment: From looking at your solution, I see it doing the rest calls in a single thread and on the driver itself.  Am I looking at your code correctly?

Comment: Yes, any suggestions for improvement welcome... the API call does not need to scale (it cannot do the pagination in parallel) so it runs on the smallest possible cluster. But if there is a better way let me know...